# How to make a function wait for another function to finish running inside a JobService

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, runnable, android-thread

I have a JobService that has to get location and send it to a web service, the problem is that my sendLocation() function doesn't wait for getLocation() to finish and thus it doesn't send any data, I know that getLocation() is working since I already set some tags but by the time it is done sendLocation() has already started to execute.

my onStartJob looks like this

```
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        doBackgroundWork(params);
        return true;
    }
```

and my doBackgroundWork() like this

```
private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                getLocation();
                sendLocation();

                jobFinished(params, false);
            }
        }).start();
}
```

I already tried to put getLocation() outside doBackgroundWork() and inside onStartJob(), like this

```
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        getLocation();
        doBackgroundWork(params);
        return true;
    }
```

but it results in the same behavior.

What can I do?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `JobService` directly rather than using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) which provides a much better API surface, backward compatibility, and a large number of workarounds for existing issues in `JobScheduler`?

Comment: I'm using JobService as a JobScheduler, the reason is that so far is the only method that has allowed me to call my functions even when the CPU is in deep sleep mode